# How can I get the offset coordinates of a background image, when the onclick event is on the foreground image?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, mouseevent, offset

I have an image -- it's a wiring diagram -- where I can click and read the offsetX and offsetY coordinates. That's no problem. On this image, a specific localized region is shown as selected by use of another image in the form of a rectangle. In other words, a rectangle highlights specific portions of the wiring diagram. Ergo, I'm overlaying one image on top of another image.

When the user clicks inside the rectangle, the event object shows the offsetX and offsetY positions, with respect to the rectangle image, not the wiring diagram. Again, I have no issue reading the appropriate offset coordinates when  the user clicks anywhere there are no rectangle image.

I want to retrieve the offset coordinates of the wiring diagram when the user clicks anywhere on or within the rectangle, as if the rectangle image doesn't exist.

For example, the user clicks on a component and the offset XY coordinates are 45 and 100. Now, the user selects this component and clicks in the exact same spot as the first time. The offset XY coordinates are read again. However, instead of reading 45 and 100, the values are 10 and 12. I want it such that if the user clicks on the rectangle, it's offset coordinates will read the 45 and 100, not the 10 and 12.j

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant portion of the HTML

```
<div id="leftpane">
    <div id="wiring_diagram_div" style="height: 800px; position: relative;">
        <img id="wiring_diagram_page1" use="#MAP_JK1" src="wiring_diagram_page1.gif" onclick="zoomOnImage(event, 1);" />
        <map id="MAP_JK1" name="MAP_JK1">

        <!-- There are many more area tags. This is just an example -->
            <area shape="rect" coords="435, 550, 443, 563" onclick="javascript:selectComponent();" />
        </map>

        <!-- There are 3 rectangles but only one is enabled at a time. A rectangle is enabled based upon the user selecting a component and the particular rectangle displayed is dependent on the size of the component selected by the user.  -->
        <div id="rectangle1" name="rectangles">
            <img id="rectangle1_1" name="rectangle" src="rectangle.gif" onclick="zoomOnComponent(event);" width="15" height="18" style="display: block;" />
            <img id="rectangle2_1" name="rectangle" src="rectangle.gif" onclick="zoomOnComponent(event);" width="22" height="19" style="display:none;" />
            <img id="rectangle3_1" name="rectangle" src="rectangle.gif" onclick="zoomOnComponent(event);" width="28" height="21" style="display:none;" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to get the offset of the overlay rectangle that was clicked, and add the offset XY of the click event to those values. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It makes sense but I'm not quite sure how to connect the dots. Can you please provide an example? I think I get the offset XY of the click event, which is relative to the rectangles div. Then, I would shoot up the chain and work with whatever offset I have with the background image. Add the two together and that would be the equivalent offset, as if the rectangle was not present?